# Develoment Environment

Tags: php, mysql, development-environment

I'm looking for advice on setting up a development environment.  There's an already existing application that's very large in size that I'm working on.  The problem is I'm developing on the server where the app exist for development.  Is there a way to use WAMP or another server for the app and connect to the already existing MySQL database for development and testing?

Or does someone have a better idea for development and testing?

Comment: You should not develop on the productive database. Copy the database to your local WAMP (or another server).

Comment: 1) Copy database and copy code. 2) Setup environment locally 3) ? 4) Profit!

Comment: I know I shouldn't that's why I'm asking for a different solution. The code at the moment is copied and file renamed... and coding in notepad.  Also the DB is huge there's no way to download it to my computer it would take 2 years to do so.  Also there's nothing being inserted into the db but rather only selecting and displaying results.

Comment: Use a virtualbox that replicates the production environment (same OS, same versions, same configuration, etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1** Make a `database dump` (export) from your production database:

```
$ mysqldump -u root -p[root_password] [database_name] > dumpfilename.sql
```

**2** [Create a new database on a remote place such as AWS](http://aws.amazon.com)

**3** Import the dump into your newly created database:

```
$ mysql -u root -p[root_password] [database_name] < dumpfilename.sql
```

**4** Connect your local application to it

**5** [Start coding](https://php.net)

Comment: Go to the db (phpmyadmin), SQL tab, type in -  mysqldump -u root -p[the password for the db - why would I need this if I'm in the db?] [the database name - If I'm in phpmyadmin do I still need this if there's one db? ] > dumpfilename.sql ?

Comment: No, with phpmyadmin you just use the tools provided by the graphical user interface

Comment: Linux command line. http://www.techspot.com/guides/835-linux-command-line-basics